# Prove that $\mu((0,\infty))=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a measure on the Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and assume that there is a $K\geq 0$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $$\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} e^{nx}\ d\mu \leq K.$$ Show that $\mu((0,\infty))=0.$

My attempt: Let $X=(0,\infty).$ Let $f_n$ be the sequence of functions on $X$ such that for all $x\in X$, $f_n(x)=e^{nx}$. Since the sequence $\left\{\displaystyle\int_X f_n(x)\ d\mu(x)\right\}$ is bounded and $f_n$ is an increasing sequence of nonnegative $\mu-$measurable functions on $X$, then by Beppo Levi Lemma, $f_n$ converges pointwise to a measurable function $f$ on $X$ that is finite almost everywhere on $X$ and $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_X e^{nx}\ d\mu=\displaystyle\int_X f\ d\mu<\infty.$$ Now if we assume that $\mu(X)>0$, I don't see the contradiction here. By the way this is a qualifier practice problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int e^{nx} d\mu \geq \int_{(a,\infty)} e^{nx} d\mu$ for any $a>0$.  Hence $K \geq \int e^{nx} d\mu \geq e^{na} \mu (a,\infty)$. Since this is true for each $n$ we get $\mu (a,\infty)=0$. Since $a>0$ is arbitrary we get $\mu (0,\infty)=0$.

Comment: Thank you! To complete the proof, we have $\mu((0,\infty)=\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n},\infty)\right)\leq \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(\frac{1}{n},\infty) = 0.$

Comment: @JohnThompson Yes, I just left the last step to you.

Answer (score 0):

Define $X_n = (1/n;\infty)$, then we have for every $m\in \mathbb{N}$
$$ e^{m/n} \mu(X_n) \leq \int_{X_n} e^{mx} d\mu \leq \int_\mathbb{R} e^{mx} d\mu \leq K $$
This implies $\mu(X_n)=0$. Use this to show $\mu(X)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $e^{X_n}$. Thanks!

Comment: I actually wanted to integrate over $X_n$... was already a bit late.